# How can I convert an Excel date into a Timestamp for Java?

Tags: java, excel, datetime

I am receiving csv files from that someone wrote in excel, and I need to parse those files into my database.

However, when I try to parse the date into a timestamp, it tells me the format is incorrect and expects YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss

There are two possible sollutions to this and I am not sure which one is actually doable.
 1. Have excel convert the dates to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss before exporting the csv
 2. Convert the Excel date format in Java somehow.

I tried to change the format in Excel, but I did not see any formatting option that resulted in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss  the closest I got was YY-MMM-DD or MM/DD/YY

Which is the better sollution, 1 or 2, and how do I do it?

Edit Relevant Javacode snippet:

```
 public static List<AffiliateEntry> convert(ArrayList<String[]> collection) {
            List<AffiliateEntry> entryList = new ArrayList<AffiliateEntry>();
            HashMap<String, Integer> columnIndex = new HashMap();
            for (int col_index = 0; col_index < collection.get(0).length; col_index++)                   {
                columnIndex.put(collection.get(0)[col_index].trim(), col_index);
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < collection.size(); i++) {
                String[] row = collection.get(i);
                AffiliateEntry convertedEntry = new AffiliateEntry();
                int dateIndx = columnIndex.get("Date") != null ? columnIndex.get("Date") : 0;
                Timestamp date = (row[dateIndx] != null && !row[dateIndx].isEmpty()) ? Timestamp.valueOf(row[dateIndx]) :
                new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                convertedEntry.setReport_date(date);
        ....//more things to convert
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can make custom formats in excel. according to [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-HA102809474.aspx), just click on the Custom category and add yyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. Apply this format to all cells needed

Comment: Please show us your code and the csv line.

Comment: @Ploutox Please post that as an answer, it's the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to modify the format of the original dataset.

You can easily create a custom format and apply it to all the cells needed in excel. Just select the cells, right-click > format > Custom and add the new format : `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Source : [Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-HA102809474.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 2.

You can use the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class to parse the date when it is formatted in a different format, for example:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
Date dateStr = formatter.parse(strDate);
```

Comment: A suitable handcrafted format string should be what is needed here.